# Random chat according to the map?

Tags: php

How would you develop of random chat feature, but you'll have to allow the user to select the country he wants the "random chatter" to be from.
without collecting any data from the users.

Comment: This Kind of questions cannot be answered. This is not a real question at all.

Comment: This question is not very well worded, but the basic point is still very understandable. I don't think it deserves four downvotes. @Orel I think you can get more responses if you re-word your question with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to track down your user's country according to their IP. See [Identifying the country of visitor to my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180359/identifying-the-country-of-visitor-to-my-website)